# Getting a 400 bad request when using SSL on port other than 443?

Tags: android

I've got a server serving at port 9443. It's using an ssl cert signed by godaddy for "example.com". I try to connect to a url like:

```
https://example.com:9443/api/v1/foo
```

and that works fine from an ios app I've written, and desktop browsers. If I try connecting from an android phone, I get a 400 bad request response. I tried the same through chrome for android, it gives me:

```
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

The server is also listening to port 443, using a self-signed cert, and the android client works ok there (I do need some additional code there to make my app trust the self-signed cert).

Is there some restriction in android where https must use port 443? I was thinking that since I'm using a legitimate ssl cert, I wouldn't need any custom code to force the app to trust the cert. My connection code:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
Result result = new Result(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); // 400
response.getStatusLine().toString(); // HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you accessing through a proxy by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities, I think.

Searching for `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED android` leads me to [this page](http://digitaljive.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/bug-android-error-111-neterr_tunnel_connection_failed/), where the author claims:

> Android for some unknown reason will not allow you to use unstandard
>   ports for SSL (i.e. only port 443 works when using https)
>
> I confirmed this by trying a SSL website on port 2000 using my wifes
>   iphone on AT&T. Sure enough it worked fine. So its not AT&T. Also
>   worth pointing out it works fine on wifi.
>
> Hopefully this is just a bug and will be fixed in the future.

However, [this site](https://support.servertastic.com/error-111-net-err-tunnel-connection-failed-unknown-error/) claims that error occurs when accessing a site through a proxy. It's possible you may have a proxy configured on your Android phone that it's trying to use somehow.

The easiest way to tell which world you're in would be to check from a different Android phone, if you have one.

Comment: Huh what the heck - if I connect to my home wifi here (completely separate from my server machine), then the connection goes through fine on port 9443. If I turn wifi off, and am just connected through data on AT&T, I'll get the 400 error.

Comment: That's pretty strong evidence for the "Android bug" case. (Out of curiosity, I wonder what happens if you tether through an Android phone and use a desktop browser...)

Comment: Oh and I'm not connected to any proxy on the android phone.

Comment: I'd grab as much information as you can and file a bug report. See if there's anything in the ADB logs, too.

Comment: Well I've never seen a bug in android so it's probably somewhere else. I'll dig into it some more. Nothing in the ADB logs. I tried using the URLConnection class as well, instead of HttpClient, same result. Thanks so much for the info!

Answer (score 0):

It may help you

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }



public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this Httpclient instead of deafault

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing for the self-signed cert today. But I wanted to move away from this to the real cert.

Comment: Actually this still doesn't work when using a port other than 443.